# Duplicating an entire disk

Tags: macos, disk-utility, external-disk, command-line

I need to replace a fairly new disk with a *physically* smaller one.  It's not bootable: a Time Machine partition, an HFS+ storage partition, and an ExFat that has a trivial amount of Windows storage on it.

Can `dd` duplicate the whole thing, partition map and three partitions?

Or do I have to partition it first and then do each partition?

Or should I just use Disk Utility as in [How to clone an entire disk with Lion (+Rescue) & Bootcamp Partitions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27231/how-to-clone-an-entire-disk-with-lion-rescue-bootcamp-partitions)

Actually, given the 4TB size, and the throughput of USB, I guess I need not the easiest method, but the fastest.  That's probably Disk Utility, but it won't do the whole disk.  I have to first match the partitions, then do them individually.

UPDATE: The reason for copying from a **new** disk to another of the same capacity is that the old one was too large to squeeze into the bag for travel.  Unfortunately, the ***new*** drive failed during the copy!!  I had to start a new set of backups on the smaller one.  Hopefully when I come back in three months, I can recover data and get my money back.  Western Digital, only a month old with a three-year warranty.

Comment: You cannot `dd` a larger disk to a smaller disk.

Comment: Do you know what the word "physically" means?

Comment: @WGroleau Obviously the physical size (e.g. form factor) is completely irrelevant here and you should add the sizes of the two disks in TB/GB. Also add the physical block sizes (either 512 or 4096 - the final gpts differ slightly).

Comment: You asked in the comment following my first comment, "Do you know what the word "physically" means?", and I'm assuming in the context of `dd` it was used such that the destination disk capacity is smaller then the source disk capacity, and if that's the wrong assumption then your question is poorly written!   klanomath's comment points out exactly why!

Comment: The physical size is not relevant to the copy; it was mentioned to avoid wasted advice to keep using a perfectly good disk that won't fit in my luggage.  I didn't mention the capacity at all, because obviously they have to be the same.

Comment: @WGroleau They don't have to be the same: the destination disk should have the same size or larger (when both have the same physical block size). If the source disk has a pbs of 512 and the destination disk 4096 the dest disk has to be slightly larger (or more) than the source disk **and** fulldisk-to-fulldisk dd won't work (and vice-versa)...

Comment: If the destination is larger, it's difficult to get access to the extra space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a more complete answer, by all means, post.

'dd' is simpler, if you get the details right on the command line.

Disk Utility however, may be faster even though you have to partition and then restore each partition in turn.  This is because 'dd' is going to copy all the unused blocks.  In my case, with both of them on USB 2.0, if the drive hadn't failed, it would have taken sixty hours.

Also, if the two drives don't have exactly the same number of bytes, 'dd' is not good.  If the target is smaller, the O.S. will try to use blocks that don't exist (or it will fail to copy at all).  If the target is bigger, the extra blocks will be inaccessible.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to replace a fairly new disk with a physically smaller one.  a
>   Time Machine partition, an HFS+ storage partition, and an ExFat that
>   has a trivial amount of Windows storage on it.
>   *Can dd duplicate the whole thing, partition map and three partitions?*

You may want to consider a utility like Carbon Copy Cloner. This will allow you to adjust the size of the hfs+ and exfat partitions. You will need to make the time machine partition the same size.  Time machine uses hardlinks. I think it is best to use the dd command for the copy.

Yes, the drive must be the same size or bigger than you old drive. If bigger, do the dd copy. run disk utility verify and fix to expand to the larger size.  I would try this on the timemachine partition. Another thought would be to merge the unused space with the last partition.  Be sure to use the /Applications/Utilities/Terminal to check the exact size of the disk. dd is a sector by sector copy.   Use the df command to get exact size information.

```
mac $ df
Filesystem    512-blocks       Used  Available Capacity   iused     ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk1    1951137792 1234788896  715836896    64% 154412610  89479612   63%   /
devfs                395        395          0   100%       684         0  100%   /dev
map -hosts             0          0          0   100%         0         0  100%   /net
map auto_home          0          0          0   100%         0         0  100%   /home
/dev/disk5    1949177344 1949161960      15384   100% 243645243      1923  100%   /Volumes/3T Mac Mini Backup
/dev/disk2s2  1952853344   13180368 1939672976     1%   1647544 242459122    1%   /Volumes/--Mojave--
/dev/disk4s2  1951855464 1912489144   39366320    98% 239061141   4920790   98%   /Volumes/4T Virtual Machines
/dev/disk4s3  5859978200 4661453928 1198524272    80% 582681739 149815534   80%   /Volumes/4T Backup - Time Machine
/dev/disk3s4  1951171880 1454044824  497127056    75% 181755601  62140882   75%   /Volumes/3T iMac G3 Backup
/dev/disk3s5  1956993296 1063139096  893854200    55% 132892385 111731775   54%   /Volumes/3T VM Backup
mac $ df -h
Filesystem      Size   Used  Avail Capacity   iused     ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk1     930Gi  589Gi  341Gi    64% 154412633  89479589   63%   /
devfs          198Ki  198Ki    0Bi   100%       684         0  100%   /dev
map -hosts       0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%         0         0  100%   /net
map auto_home    0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%         0         0  100%   /home
/dev/disk5     929Gi  929Gi  7.5Mi   100% 243645243      1923  100%   /Volumes/3T Mac Mini Backup
/dev/disk2s2   931Gi  6.3Gi  925Gi     1%   1647544 242459122    1%   /Volumes/--Mojave--
/dev/disk4s2   931Gi  912Gi   19Gi    98% 239061141   4920790   98%   /Volumes/4T Virtual Machines
/dev/disk4s3   2.7Ti  2.2Ti  572Gi    80% 582681739 149815534   80%   /Volumes/4T Backup - Time Machine
/dev/disk3s4   930Gi  693Gi  237Gi    75% 181755601  62140882   75%   /Volumes/3T iMac G3 Backup
/dev/disk3s5   933Gi  507Gi  426Gi    55% 132892385 111731775   54%   /Volumes/3T VM Backup
mac $
```

You could get a smaller drive enclosure and swap in your old drive.

Here are an example of the dd command:

```
dd if=/dev/disk0 bs=4096m | dd of=/dev/disk2 bs=4096m
```

the bs needs to be large. doesn't need to match the actual bs. what I do is mount the drive. do a df. unmount the drive. do a df so I can figure out what the drive name is.

You may want to consider putting your critical data in the cloud.  dropbox.com

Comment: When I have done things like that before, it was not possible to "merge the unused space with the last partition."  'dd' made the target drive seem the same size as the original.  Neither disk utility nor some other tool I tried was able to see any unused space.